# Collecting data from two data frames to store in a new data frame

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I would like to somehow create a third data frame which is a combination of two existing data frames.

The dates in both the data frames are not consistent, I would like to take the dates common to both data frames and load them into the third data frame along with 'company_name' from the first and 'count' from second data frame.

The input looks like this:

```
**Data Frame 1:**
Date    Company_Name
10/18/2013  AFAM
10/17/2013  SMN
10/16/2013  SMN
10/15/2013  AFAM
10/14/2013  AFAM

**Data Frame 2:**
data_date   normalized_company_name count
10/18/2013  Almost Family   1
10/16/2013  somename    2
10/15/2013  somename    3
10/14/2013  Almost Family   4
10/13/2013  Almost Family   5
```

And this is what I want:

```
**Data Frame 3:**
Date    Company_Name    count
10/18/2013  AFAM    1
10/15/2013  AFAM    4
```

I would also like to mention that the format of the date columns in all data frames is `Date`. I have done a lot of acrobatics with this already but can't seem to reach a conclusion. I would really appreciate if I could get some help on this.

**Here is some code I have been trying to use which does not seem to work**:

```
finalData$Total.Job.Count[
  as.character(finalData$Date) %in%    
    intersect(as.character(finalData$Date[finalData$Company_Name=='AFAM']) ,
  as.character(jobs$data_date[jobs$normalized_company_name=='Almost Family'])) &
    finalData$Company_Name=='AFAM']
<-
jobs$job_count_total[
  as.character(jobs$data_date) %in% 
    intersect(as.character(finalData$Date[finalData$Company_Name=='AFAM']) ,
  as.character(jobs$data_date[jobs$normalized_company_name=='Almost Family'])) & 
    jobs$normalized_company_name=='Almost Family']
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: `?merge` may be what you want...? The formatting of this question could be much simpler, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
merge( finalData, jobs[ , c("data_date", "count")] , by.x=1, by.y=1 )
```